# Creating a new theme in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello everyone I am just few days experience to android, learning..
I am trying to make a app which uses themes, but facing a problem hope you could help me out.

This is my Layout

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
android:paddingStart="10dp"
android:paddingEnd="10dp"
style="?TextColor"
/>
```

This is my style.xml

```
<!-- GENERIC STYLES -->
    <style name="App_text_color_white" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
    </style>
    <style name="App_text_color_black" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/Black</item>
    </style>

<!-- RED Theme Styles ####################################### -->
    <style name="App_Bg_img_red" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/red_abstract_background_blur</item>
    </style>

<!-- RED Theme -->
    <style name="NoteItTheme.RED">
        <item name="pageBackgroundImage">@style/App_Bg_img_red</item>
        <item name="TextColor">@style/App_text_color_black</item>
    </style>
```

Below is my attr.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- View styles -->
    <attr name="pageBackgroundImage" format="reference" />
    <attr name="TextColor" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

I am setting the theme in `onCreate` method by using following code

```
this.setTheme(R.style.NoteItTheme_RED);
```

Now the problem is setting of background image is fine which means theme is working.
But I the TextColor is not changing its always white, with or without applying theme.

Any idea what is wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance
here is the screenshot

Sorry I forgot to mention:
the background image is set for the root RelativeLayout and the textcolor I want to set is for a ListView having Checked TextBox

[image: here is the screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use

```
<style name="image" parent="@android:style/Widget.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:background">#000000  <!-use your selector for image buttons --></item>
</style>
```

in style file for background imagebuttons and following code for textviews

```
<style name="text"  parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView" > 
    <item name="android:textColor"><!-use your textcolor  --></item>     
</style>
```

edit

```
 <style name="NoteItTheme.RED">
            <item name="pageBackgroundImage">@style/App_Bg_img_red</item>
            <item name="TextColor">@style/App_text_color_black</item>
            <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/image</item>
<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/text</item>
        </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<!-- RED Theme -->
<style name="NoteItTheme.RED">
    <item name="pageBackgroundImage">@style/App_Bg_img_red</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/App_text_color_black</item>    
</style>

<style name="App_text_color_black"  parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView" > 
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/Black</item>     
</style>
```